# PHP CURL PUT from Amazon S3 stream wrapper (tcp stream)

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, vimeo-api, php-stream-wrappers

I'm trying to (PHP) cURL PUT a file from Amazon S3 to Vimeo using S3 stream wrapper `(s3://...)` and getting the follow error:

> curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type tcp_socket/ssl as a STDIO FILE in [...]

Is there a way to cURL PUT a remote file? This are the curl opts being sent:

```
$curl_opts = array(
  CURLOPT_PUT => true,
  CURLOPT_INFILE => $file, // this refers to 's3://path-to-object'
  CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $size,
  CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Expect: ', 'Content-Range: replaced...')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file to your local server before PUTting it:

```
$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "foo");
$data = file_get_contents("s3://path-to-object");
$size = strlen($data);
file_put_contents($file, $data);
$curl_opts = array(
  CURLOPT_PUT => true,
  CURLOPT_INFILE => $file, // this refers to 's3://path-to-object'
  CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $size,
  CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Expect: ', 'Content-Range: replaced...')
);
```

Comment: That's my current workaround but I'm trying to bypass that download step. Thanks!

Comment: I guess some application needs to make the data flow so I don't see a solution without downloading the file so far

Comment: When you PUT, you are uploading a concrete object. A data stream is not that. It has no finite size.